# How can I substitute the value of one string into another based on a substitution character?

Tags: c#, string

I have a rather difficult problem and I'm not sure how I can do what is needed.

I have two `string`s, `text1` and `text2`. I need to create a `result` that is based on *both* of these. `text2` has separator `"|"` so that if there are three characters in `text1` then there will be *two* separators etc.

I need to create a `result` that is `text2` without the separator and with a the corresponding character from `text1` replacing the `#`. Below I have some examples:

```
text1:   間違う      text2: ま|ちが|#      result: まちがう
text1:   立ち上げる   text2: た|#|あ|#|#    result: たちあげる
text1:   取る        text2: と|#          result: とる
```

Would appreciate advice and suggestions.

Comment: *corresponding character*, is that position-based?

Comment: Wouldn't this be just splitting text2 by the delimiter, `|`, then iterate through the parts and replace the `#` values with the index-based corresponding character from text1?

Comment: Yes I believe that would work.  Do you suggest splitting each of them and putting them into two arrays or is there an easier way that this could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to substitute each `#` within `text2` into corresponding character in `text1` treating `|` as a *delimiter*;
you can do it with a help of *Linq*:

**Code:**

```
private static String ProcessString(string text1, string text2) {
  return string.Concat(text2
    .Split('|')
    .Select((item, index) => item == "#" 
       ? text1[index].ToString() // substitute with corresponding char from text1
       : item));                 // keep as it is
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Tuple<string, string>[] tests = new[] {
  Tuple.Create("間違う",     "ま|ちが|#"),
  Tuple.Create("立ち上げる", "た|#|あ|#|#"),
  Tuple.Create("取る",       "と|#"),
};

var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => 
     $"{test.Item1,5} + {test.Item2,10} => {ProcessString(test.Item1, test.Item2)}"));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  間違う  +     ま|ちが|# => まちがう
立ち上げる +  た|#|あ|#|# => たちあげる
   取る   +          と|# => とる
```