# How can I create a string by combining two strings and using substitution?

Tags: c#

I have code that creates two strings:

```
var string1 = "ま|ちが|#";
var string2 = "間|違|う";
```

I'm looking for a way to combine these such the resulting output contains the characters from string1 but if the character is a "#" then it takes the alternate character from string2.

```
string1      string2    desired output
ま|ちが|#     間|違|う      まちがう
な|#         為|る         なる
で|き|#      出|来|る      できる
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried. You could start by splitting by `|` and then use the index to overlap.

Comment: de ja vu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58214947/how-can-i-substitute-the-value-of-one-string-into-another-based-on-a-substitutio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IndexOf()` method like

```
var hashIndex = string1.IndexOf('#');
if(hashIndex > 0) {
Console.WriteLine(string1.Substring(0, string1.Length - 2) + string2[hashindex]);
}
```